# How can I put titles in ViewPager using fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I am using ViewPager to allow user to swipe between fragments.

How can I add a the title of each fragment to the screen?

```
package com.multi.andres;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator;
import com.viewpagerindicator.TitleProvider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class ViewPagerFragment extends FragmentActivity{

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter; //contiene el pager adapter
    private static String[] titulosPaginas = { "APP 1", "APP 2" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.lcmeter); //layout que contiene el ViewPager

        initialisePaging(); //inicializo las paginas
    }

    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentPrueba1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentPrueba2.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

        //Agrega los titulos
        TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.titulos);    //layout XML
        titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    /** *************************************************************************************************
    /** Clase:   public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TitleProvider
    /** Notas:   extends FragmentPagerAdapter permite el uso de las paginas de ViewPager pero con Fragments
    /**          implements TitleProvider permite el uso de los titulos en las paginas
    /** Funcion: crea paginas por las cuales deslizarse horizontalmente las cuales son usadas
    ****************************************************************************************************/
    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TitleProvider {

        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public String getTitle(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return titulosPaginas[position];    // titulo de la pagina
        }

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

    }

}
```

But it doesn't show the titles of ViewPager and I don't know why. I used ViewPager with titles before but not with fragments and I cannot get titles working now.

Comment: Are you saying that each Tab has its own title?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can also use Jake Wharton's [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) library to get the desired effect. Davek804's answer works too, but it requires you to reference the entire ActionBarSherlock library, which isn't as preferable if you only need a `ViewPager` that supports custom/styled titles.

Setting it up to work correctly is simply a matter of writing a tiny bit of XML, initializing your `ViewPager` in your `Activity`, and implementing a `FragmentAdapter` (which `extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TitleProvider`) to specify which pages hold which `Fragment`s.

1. XML layout

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
           android:id="@+id/titles"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
           android:id="@+id/pager"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"/>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Initialize in your `Activity`

   ```
   //Set the pager with an adapter
   ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
   pager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

   //Bind the title indicator to the adapter
   TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.titles);
   titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
   ```
3. Implement a `CustomFragmentAdapter`

   ```
   public static class CustomFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
           implements TitleProvider {

           public static final int POSITION_PAGE_1 = 0;
           public static final int POSITION_PAGE_2 = 1;
           public static final int POSITION_PAGE_3 = 2;

           private static final String[] TITLES = new String[] { 
               "Title 1", 
               "Title 2", 
               "Title 3" 
           };

           public static final int NUM_TITLES = TITLES.length;

           public CustomFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {      
               super(fm);
           }

           @Override
           public Fragment getItem(int position) {     
               switch (position) {
               case POSITION_TITLE_1:              
                   return PageOneFragment.newInstance();
               case POSITION_TITLE_2: 
                   return PageTwoFragment.newInstance();
               case POSITION_TITLE_3:
                   return PageThreeFragment.newInstance();         
               }
               return null;
           }

           @Override
           public int getCount() {
               return NUM_TITLES;
           }

           @Override
           public String getTitle(int position) {
               return TITLES[position % NUM_TITLES].toUpperCase();
           }
       }
   ```

---

### Edit:

The [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) library supports the titling features:

1. `TitlePageIndicator`

   [image: TitlePageIndicator]
2. `TabPageIndicator`

   [image: TabPageIndicator]
3. `CirclePageIndicator`

   [image: CirclePageIndicator]

Comment: also note that there are some other important method you should consider when you initialize your `ViewPager`. for instance, `pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(CustomFragmentAdapter.NUM_TITLES-1);` will prevent your `ViewPager` from destroying off-screen `Fragment`s (which you may or may not decide is necessary in your application).

Comment: Thanks you, but how i have to create the newInstance() method inside each fragment ? Is completely necessary ? If you pay a look at my program it seems to instanciate the classes and then whithout creating newInstance(). You tell me to use TabPageIndicator in XML is it the same as TitlePageIndicator ?

Comment: Oh sorry about that... I copied and pasted some of the code from an app I wrote. If your `Fragment` doesn't take any arguments, then you can just call the default constructor for each `Fragment` instead.

Comment: I put an answer because a had to put some code please pay a look :)

Comment: Take a look at some of my code on GitHub. The [**`MatchPagerActivity`**](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/scouting-manager-old/blob/master/src/com/cmu/scout/ui/MatchPagerActivity.java) shows a `ViewPager` on the screen (in this case, it is a `TabPagerIndicator`), and sets the screen layout given in an [**xml file**](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/scouting-manager-old/blob/master/res/layout/match_scout_pager.xml). The `MatchFragmentAdapter` is given as an inner-nested class in the `MatchPagerActivity` class (see the first link, bottom of the page).

Comment: Are you still having issues with your code? I couldn't tell after you added the "edit".

Comment: The only problem i have now is that titles are shown on the bottom of the screen instead of top and i dont know how to change that position, but now i can call my Fragments but i cannot use functions like Typeface.createFromAsset to use custom fonts unless the Fragments i call were FragmentActivity but it seems i cannot use FragmentActivity on pages :/ Thank you very much for the help you are giving to me :)

Comment: the reason why the titles are on the bottom of the page is because you have put the `TitlePageIndicator` view under the `ViewPager` in your `LinearLayout`. copy and paste the `TitlePagerIndicator` above the `ViewPager` and it should view correctly, I think.

Comment: That is correct, `FragmentActivity extends Activity`... it is a subclass of `Activity` that you can use with the `Fragment`s from the Android Support Package. Adding a `FragmentActivity` as one of the pages wouldn't make any sense (you need to add `Fragment`s for each page, not `Activity`s).

Comment: Lastly, try this code in your `Fragment`s: `Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), font);` (these are called *methods* by the way, not *functions* :P).

Comment: Thanks you !! Now it is on the top !! :) I will continue developing my application i learned a lot thanks you very much :)

Comment: I'm getting `TitleProvider cannot be resolved to a type` error. Which package I need to import to avoid this?

Comment: As this answer is accepted, I am pretty sure its worth trying.First can anyone tell me how to add Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator  library to the project.I downloaded it but unable to import it to eclipse.Its showing " No projects are found to import".please help me

Answer (score 11):

Or if you don't like to use from third-part library, you can use support v4 PagerTabStrip class.
For example:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pts_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

and in PagerAdapter override getPageTitle method:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter  {
    ...
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return String.valueOf(position);
    }
}
```

You can access for xml element from code like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.pager);
    ...
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    // Add custom adapter
    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Get PagerTabStrip
    PagerTabStrip strip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pts_main);
    strip.setDrawFullUnderline(false);
    ...
```

I hope it will helps for someone

Comment: That's most easiest and convenient code only with few lines of code for showing tabs in view pager without using any third party library.

Answer (score 0):

Where mine says SherlockFragmentActivity, you can just have FragmentActivity. getSupportActionBar can be getActionBar().

```
public class Polling extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements OnMenuItemClickListener {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);
        bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.login),
                LoginFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.economics),
                EconFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.elections),
                ElectionsFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.politics),
                PoliticsFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.science),
                ScienceFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.finance),
                FinanceFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.religion),
                ReligionFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.military),
                MilitaryFragment.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(R.string.international),
                InternationalFragment.class, null); 
    }

    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final ActionBar mActionBar;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
            mViewPager = pager;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
            tab.setTag(info);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mActionBar.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return (SherlockFragment)Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            //Log.v(TAG, "clicked");
            Object tag = tab.getTag();
            for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
                if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
        }
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {}
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Lockwood Thanks you :) I still have a problem :/ It is my XML:

**lcmeter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/titulos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Whit my original code in the first post if a put "TitlePageIndicator" before "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" i can see the titles but i cannot swype only clicking the titles change the pages and my fragments are not showed but whit the XML on that way i can swype through my fragments but i cannot see the titles :/. I tried whit constructors on this way:

```
package com.multi.andres;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator;
import com.viewpagerindicator.TitleProvider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class ViewPagerFragment extends FragmentActivity{

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter; //contiene el pager adapter
    String[] titulosPaginas = { "APP 1", "APP 2" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.lcmeter); //layout que contiene el ViewPager

        initialisePaging(); //inicializo las paginas
    }

    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentPrueba1.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentPrueba2.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

        //Agrega los titulos
        TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.titulos);    //layout XML
        titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    /** *************************************************************************************************
    /** Clase:   public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TitleProvider
    /** Notas:   extends FragmentPagerAdapter permite el uso de las paginas de ViewPager pero con Fragments
    /**          implements TitleProvider permite el uso de los titulos en las paginas
    /** Funcion: crea paginas por las cuales deslizarse horizontalmente las cuales son usadas
    ****************************************************************************************************/
    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements TitleProvider {

        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public String getTitle(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return titulosPaginas[position];    // titulo de la pagina
        }

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            try {
                FragmentPrueba1.class.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

    }

}
```

But i have a FC when i open the application. Here is my fragment both are equal:

```
package com.multi.andres;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class FragmentPrueba1 extends Fragment {

    FragmentPrueba1 (){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.prueba1, container, false);

    }

}
```

It is fragments XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#FF0000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Numero 1 !!" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Esto es un boton XD" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have read about Fragments but i cannot get working Fragments whit titles and it doesnt make sense :/ I am new at this but i am learning and is pretty complicated to me this kind of things thank you very much for your help i really appreciate it :)

***EDIT:***

I think i have founded the problem, it is not on Java code, the problem is on XML file ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/titulos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That seems to "get over" the titles because if i use XML file of Google example which adds android:layout_weight="1" on android.support.v4.view.ViewPager, i can see the titles on the bottom of the screen, not on top instead but is a progress :)