# How to use viewpagerindicator with ViewPager in Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I want to use [viewpagerindicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) with `ViewPager` in my android application. I've created `ViewPager`, now I want to display the title of each page in the `ViewPager`. After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10039279/1341006) I came to know that viewpagerindicator will be helpful. Now the problem is that how can I use this project in my project. I tried adding from `properties --> java build path --> Libraries --> add external class folders` but it doesn't helped.
I also tried to compile the libraries downloaded from http://viewpagerindicator.com/, but that gives me a bunch of `The method setViewPager(ViewPager) of type LinePageIndicator must override a superclass method` type errors.

I want to use `TabPageIndicator` and `TitlePageIndicator` from viewpagerindicator project in my application as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10039279/1341006).

Comment: You could use the new android PagerTabStrip, it works very nice and is backwards compatible.
Here is a nice example project, using the android PagerTabStrip: http://code.google.com/p/viewpage-title-project/ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html The only thing you need to do is importing the android support library version 9: Right click your project --> android tools --> add support library.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the source code of that project
2. In your Eclipse workspace: File > New > Project... > Android > Android project from existing code
3. As the location choose viewpagerindicator/library (this should create the library project in your workspace)
4. Right click on your project > Properties...
5. Android > Library > Add...
6. Select the viewpagerindicator project you have created with previous steps.
7. Follow the instructions about how to include a view pager indicator in your layouts as on http://viewpagerindicator.com/#usage

Comment: I tried this but this gives me a bunch of `the method setViewPager(ViewPager) of type LinePageIndicator must override a superclass method` type errors in the library project.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761888/override-annotation-error-android-prefs#comment15604122_4762015