# ViewPager Not showing the menus

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-appcompat

I'm working on sample viewpager using fragment. What I want is to show the fragment menus change dynamically once I swipe from one to another. I'm using AppCompat library. I'm getting the menus, but not on actionbar. Please help me on this.

My code goes like this.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ActionBar actionBar;
    ViewPager pager;
    Tab tab;
    int selectedPage = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){

            public void onPageSelected(int position){
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                selectedPage = position;
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        };

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);

        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(manager);

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);


        TabListener tabListener = new TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        //Creating tabs
        tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Fragment1").setTabListener(tabListener);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Fragment2").setTabListener(tabListener);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }
}
```

Fragment1 and Fragment2. java

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu, android.view.MenuInflater)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment2, menu);

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: do you mean TitleProvider? it will shows the titles of your fragments on viewpager..

Comment: or else you can proceed with TitlePageIndicator. check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037887/how-can-i-put-titles-in-viewpager-using-fragments

Comment: No. What I mean is I want to show menu option called "set" on fragment1 and "get" option on fragment2. How can I dynamically show that.

Comment: @Lokesh: and it should appear on actionbar.

Comment: Menu options shows on actionbar only.. currently where it is showing??

Answer (score 0):

Just give a trail by Change your  method From:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment2, menu);

    }
```

To:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment2, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }
```

And change your item in menu.xml

```
<item
            android:id="@+id/something"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic"
            yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="@string/something"/>
```

Dont forgot to add `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <item
        android:id="@+id/something"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic"
        android:title="@string/something"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>